# Can't open Terminal!

Tags: default, transparency

I've customized the terminal to put a transparency. But I put a start command "dir" to see what happen, now I open the terminal ,he makes a dir and closes. Before I could to change the default profile .

How I can edit the profile o change to the Default profile?

Comment: for now, press control alt f1 to get a terminal

Answer (score 10):

You need to *remove* the folder `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal` (where the profiles are stored), and log out and back in *before* opening the terminal again(!!). 
If you open `gnome-terminal` before logging out/in, the existing profile settings will simply be recreated (including the error).

*So:*

1. remove the folder `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal`
2. log out and back in. You will lose the possible settings changes you made, but you will have your `gnome-terminal` back.

#### Note

*from the GUI (nautilus) (since the terminal is not available :) )*
`~` stands for your home directory. If you browse (in `nautilus`) into your home directory and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> the folder `.gconf` becomes visible.

---

***NB***
This answer was written for 15.xx, no longer applicable from 16.04 and later.

Comment: Where is this directory?

Comment: @freaker see my updated answer.

Comment: There is no such directory

Comment: @JulianLai nope, not in 16.04.

Comment: Downvote there is no such directory in 16.04. Please mention ubuntu version your solution is for.

Comment: You should have mentioned the version. You can still mention it now.

Answer (score 4):

By default, Ubuntu comes with 2 terminal emulators actually: one is `gnome-terminal` and the other is [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/), and as others suggested, there is always virtual `tty` consoles (which you can access through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> , or really any f key from 1 to 6). Now, open `xterm` and run `gnome-terminal -e 'YOLOSWAG'` (note that  YOLOSWAG is just place holder, could be anything; the real purpose here is to bring up gnome-terminal complaining about a non-existent command being given to the -e flag, which stands for executing a command with gnome-terminal; read `man gnome-terminal` for more info on that). Now when you have `gnome-terminal` window open, you can right click and edit the profiles. Close the window (don't click <kbd>relaunch</kbd>) and reopen the `gnome-terminal` again.[image]

In the image up above you can see that I've put custom command `mkdir YOLO` , which prevented the `gnome-terminal` window staying open (yes, in reality, your terminal was opening, just too fast and exited right away). I've called the terminal with the method described above.

Comment: Interesting idea :)

Answer (score 0):

**Before typing the following line: remember that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> is your friend!**  (This will bring you back here!)

Change to TTY2 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and log in.

Install `dconf-editor`, because IMHO, a GUI is a good choice here:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Now go back to TTY7 (normally) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Open the application with:

```
dconf-editor
```

and open this path in the tree:

```
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings
```

Open the profiles as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

and revert your changes.

### Done! :-)

Answer (score 0):

if your gnome terminal isnt opening, try reinstalling it and if it doesnt work even then, install a different terminal emulator; i installed Konsole and it works just the same as the gnome-terminal. good luck.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer and should be posted as such.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something is wrong with your **~/.bashrc** file, like containing

> source ~/.profile

On my occasion, I just opened fish, and the terminal pops out correctly, then I checked my .bashrc file and deleted the wrong line.
Then the terminal is back to work again!

Maybe this way can help you, but please take it seriously, deleting wrong may have an effect on your system.

Answer (score 0):

This is alternative software of built-in Terminal. I just copied [suggestion form F1iX](https://askubuntu.com/a/1345167/789450).

The alternative software is called "Termi-nator".

To install the software,

1. leave your graphical user session and switch to a plain terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+e.g. <kbd>F3</kbd>
   Or ssh to the computer remotely (like `ssh <user name>@<IP Address>` at remote computer)
2. Log in and `sudo apt-get install terminator`
3. Switch back to your graphical session with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> (or other <kbd>F</kbd>-key depending on your setup)
4. Launch `terminator`
5. Optional (set as default: `sudo apt update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`)

I had numerous issues such as Nvidia graphic card driver and Python version to Terminal malfunction, so instead of fixing and modifying them, I just installed the Termi-nator.