# Ubuntu 18 terminal not opening

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome-terminal

I just installed Ubuntu 18 on my desktop PC alongside Windows 10 and have been using Ubuntu without any problems for a couple of days. Today, when I booted up my computer, I am no longer able to open the terminal at all. I've tried restarting it multiple times, but it still won't work. If I click the terminal icon on my task bar, nothing happens. If I try opening the terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, it still doesn't work.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: If you hit `Alt+Tab` do you see that terminal is running?

Comment: No, the terminal doesn't show when I Alt+Tab

Comment: Try `Alt+F2` and run `gnome-terminal` -- what happens?

Comment: *XTerm* serves as an alternative to the Gnome Terminal. It can be installed via *Ubuntu Software* by opening the Activities window (click the Activities button or press Super), typing `xterm`, and then clicking on the corresponding entry under *Ubuntu Software*. See what happens when you run `gnome-terminal` in xterm.

Comment: When I run gnome-terminal from xterm, nothing happens..

Comment: After doing a fresh install of Ubuntu, once again the terminal is not showing when I open it. When I look in the System Monitor is shows that gnome-terminal is running, but there is no terminal visible whatsoever...

Comment: Advent of 18 has some serious bugs...I reverted back to 16

Comment: Same here. And that's crazy. One of the most important features of linux - running a console window - is broken. In a LTS *release*! (We're not talking about a dev version here!)

Comment: Any solutions for Terminal? Also Files is not opening?
I just upgraded to 19.04 now, from 18.10

Comment: @FaustoR. I just created an answer to a similar question with a solution for this issue: https://askubuntu.com/a/1143596/167115

Comment: @StefanHamcke `xfce4-terminal` is a closer alternative.

Comment: @RegisMay I've come to terms that LTS means jack appart from long support like the name says. in terms of instability and bugs, 18.04 steals all the trophies. 18.10 is night and day miles better and 19.04 is about the same as 18.10 in terms of stability, a bit better than 18.10 though.

Comment: You can download Visual Studio Code and use it's built-in terminal - I had this same problem and I fixed it using the Visual Studio Code terminal via running the various commands through that terminal to fix the Python stuff https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads

Comment: Is this question about Ubuntu 18.04 or Ubuntu 18.10? They are different releases. "Ubuntu 18" is ambiguous.

Answer (score 85):

I had the same problem. After updating Python to version 3.7, some applications like Jupyter Notebook, Meld and the terminal, did not launch.

The problem was that the symbolic link to `python3.4` was lost. Reinstalling `python3-minimal` solved it:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install python3-minimal
```

Comment: You can download Visual Studio Code and use it's built-in terminal - I had this same problem and I fixed it using the Visual Studio Code terminal via running the various commands through that terminal to fix the Python stuff https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads

Comment: JetBrain products also have terminals and works too.

Comment: i tried all other solutions in stack overflow, but only this worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: This is the easiest solution. I run this command in Visual Studio Code terminal. And it works. Thanks!

Comment: This solution deserves a medal of honor.

Comment: Thanks for the diagnosis: symlink **broken**. In my case I broke the symlink myself to use an older version of Python, so reinstalling it didn't fix that. In my case, I just undid my work, i.e. run `sudo unlink /usr/bin/python3` and then `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked great with Ubuntu 18.04 in 2022.

Answer (score 22):

The same problem happened with me. The reason is that the python version is 3.7. You can download and say any terminal for solution. I used the terminal of visual code.

The code you need to enter is:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Then you should choose a version lower than python 3.7. I choose python3.6. So I write 1 and confirm.

If the problem persists, you can rewrite it.

Example:

[image: visual code terminal with commands]

Answer (score 6):

Did you update your python3?
If yes, then this will be the solution:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open xterm.
2. Enter your username.
3. Enter your password.
4. Type this command:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config python3
   ```
5. Select option 1.
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to return to GUI

Comment: This is not helpful since option 1 may be any Python version (incl. 3.7 which seems to cause the issues).

Comment: You can download Visual Studio Code and use it's built-in terminal - I had this same problem and I fixed it using the Visual Studio Code terminal via running the various commands through that terminal to fix the Python stuff https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads

Comment: The F buttons to press may change depending on you configuration. For me, it was F2 at step 1, and F1 at step 6.

Comment: I was using Option 3 so I could use Python 3.11 on Ubuntu (following this guide  https://www.itsupportwale.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-to-python-3-11-on-ubuntu-20-04-and-22-04-lts/). I guess this is not possible this way then?

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in other answers and comments, you can try other terminals than the default `gnome-terminal`, e.g. `terminator` (I prefer this over the default terminal for other reasons anyway) or the one included in Visual Studio Code.

To install,

1. leave your graphical user session and switch to a plain terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+e.g. <kbd>F3</kbd>
2. Login and `sudo apt install terminator`
3. Switch back to your graphical session with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> (or other <kbd>F</kbd>-key depending on your setup)
4. Launch `terminator` and enjoy
5. (If needed, set as default: `sudo apt update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the alternative software. It isn't an answer for the question, but Terminator working like Terminal in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

I also second Allen's answer but you don't really need xterm. Just right-click on a point in desktop and choose "open terminal". It works that way. Then type

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

and choose a lower Python version as mentioned before.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is following command:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo cp gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-backup
sudo cp gnome-terminal.real gnome-terminal
```

**Explanation:**
First line is for backup.

Is taken from:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRwbpBol4Aw

Answer (score 1):

As the terminal does not work, you can use terminal in Intellij IDEA/VS Code/open another console by Ctrl+Alt+F3, and:

First, try:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

If you cannot `--config`("No alternatives for python3"), you need to install a new alternative. For example:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 2
```

And after all, do `--config` to revert the version(choose 3.6), as some system component relies on the libs in 3.6, and I guess that for the new 3.8, they are not installed, and **a bunch of things** will stop working!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update python then , first install tilix because terminal will not work after updating python but tilix will  work.You can perform any task in tilix like terminal.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, the `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` didn't solve. I had to undo symbolic links in `/usr/bin` like this:

from

```
sanata@sanata-desktop:/usr/bin$ ls -ght python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root    9 Aug 11 14:52 python3 -> python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root    9 Aug 11 14:52 python -> python3.8
```

to

```
sanata@sanata-desktop:/usr/bin$ ls -ght python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root    9 Aug 11 14:52 python3 -> python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root    9 Aug 11 14:52 python -> python3.6
```

Python 3.6 was before I had modified.

Additionally in some computer, the `alias` in `~\.bashrc` method works. [ref](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480555/275019)

Runtime environment:
  OS Ubuntu 18.04 AArch64

Answer (score -1):

You can use ctrl+alt+F1 up to F6 to open multiple terminals in text mode. If you want to return to GUI press ctrl+alt+F7.