# gnome-terminal failing to launch in Ubuntu 18.04 (Chrome remote desktop broke gnome-terminal)

Tags: command-line

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 a few days ago. I've been using the terminal without any issues.

When I tried opening the terminal today, it failed to launch.  I've tried launching it from the applications page as well as using the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

When running `gnome-terminal --verbose` though Tilda terminal, get the following error:

`# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached`

I've tried reinstalling the terminal by running `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-terminal`but no luck.

After some further reading, I found out that Chrome remote desktop can cause issues for the gnome-terminal to launch. I uninstalled it using `sudo apt remove chrome-remote-desktop`. The terminal launched successfully once I rebooted.

Comment: I am unable to open a terminal window. I've tried launching it from the applications screen as well as using the Alt + Ctrl + T

Comment: Please try opening a terminal with Super-F2 as shown in https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-shortcuts/

Comment: I've run the 'gnome-terminal' command in the Alt-F2 terminal, but there's no output. It just closes with nothing happening.

Comment: With any available terminal, please run `sudo apt update` and follow that up with `sudo apt full-upgrade`. Tell us if you see any errors or warnings or messages you don't understand or normally see.

Comment: Please consider title change to something like **chrome breaks `gnome-terminal`...** Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. in my case chrome-remote-desktop was the culprit as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by uninstalling Chrome remote desktop by running `$ sudo apt remove chrome-remote-desktop`

I found the solution on https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2383992

Comment: Glad it worked but I'm a little confused as to how it fixed the broken `gnome-terminal`. Was there a link you read that pointed you to this solution?

Answer (score 3):

First, try reinstalling `gnome-terminal`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-terminal
```

Next, run the following command to run `gnome-terminal` in verbose mode to see if there is any output:

```
gnome-terminal --verbose
```

If all else fails you can install `xfce4-terminal` instead:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xfce4-terminal
```

Then, you can set `xfce-terminal` as the default terminal to start on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> by first running the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Then, select the number for `xfce4-terminal` and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

You should now be able to run `xfce4-terminal` by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

[source](https://vitux.com/how-to-set-the-gnome-default-terminal-emulator-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling the terminal app by going into Ubuntu Software. Terminal Emulator should be listed in the Installed TAB.
Press Remove and after a while install it again in the All TAB.

Comment: I am not able to remove or uninstall the terminal from the Ubuntu software app.

Comment: That is because you are no admin. Install Synaptic with the same Ubuntu software app and launch that. It will have you log in and be admin. Synaptic is like Ubuntu software a tool to install and manage software and you will be amazed how much more software it shows. With synaptic you can reinstall terminal and install any other there is.

Comment: @Marc It is probably a dependency issue preventing the uninstall. See the following command to list all packages which depend on `gnome-terminal`: `apt-cache rdepends gnome-terminal | grep -P '^  [a-z].*$'`

Answer (score 1):

Removing chrome remote desktop was the solution for me - locale was fine, uninstalling and reinstalling did nothing, .bashrc was the same in ~ as it was in /etc/skel.

XTerm and UXTerm would launch and from there I could `dbus-launch gnome-terminal` successfully, but I had to `$ sudo apt remove chrome-remote-desktop` AND reboot to get gnome-terminal to launch normally.

Comment: Holy cow, thank you! I have been trying everything under the sun with locales, reinstalling things, etc, and remembered I installed chrome-remote-desktop the other day when I saw this. I removed it and gnome-terminal works again. Very strange!