# Unable to open terminal after messing with pre-installed Python

Tags: python, python3, update-alternatives

I installed Python 3.9.0 by following the instructions from http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/10/python-3-9-0-released-install-ppa-ubuntu/.

Unfortunately, I tried a not recommended instruction.

> **4.) (NOT Recommended)** To use Python 3.9 as the default `python3`, run commands:
>
> ```
> sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1
>
> sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 2
> ```

Now I can't run the terminal for either power menu or desktop, but it works from file.

Comment: So now you know why it was not recommended. What's your question?

Comment: Open terminal from files and type `gnome-terminal` in the terminal and press enter. It'll throw some error message. Paste that error message in this question

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same issue, you can revert this behaviour by first opening your files then right click anywhere and click open in terminal. You can then type:

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install python3-minimal`

This will reinstall the needed Python and restore its link. This thread saved me:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1150740