# Ubuntu 18.04.1 Can't open terminal - possibly locale related

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I'm pretty new to Linux and I came from Windows. I didn't like the collation order in the file browser so I did some reading and I tried to change it so some symbols sort above letters.

I have learnt the lesson not to mess with things I don't understand. I'm not sure how many locale commands I tried but I have really messed up my terminal. It won't open at all now, when I click it, the cursor just changes to the spinning one and nothing happens.

I have followed both answers from [Can't open Terminal!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631340/cant-open-terminal)

I have also tried `apt-get install --reinstall locales` and `sudo local-gen`.

I have tried just changing language in the UI, I even tried US/Canada/Australia. I have rebooted many times.

At the moment my /etc/default/locale file is:

```
LANG=LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_ALL=C
LANGUAGE=en_AU
```

Please let me know what i can do and thanks in advance!